Next.js Build Error with Clerk Authentication: Dynamic Route "/sign-up/[[...sign-up]]" Missing generateStaticParams()
I'm trying to build a Next.js app that integrates Clerk for authentication, but I'm encountering a build error when running npm run build. The issue seems to be related to the dynamic route for the Clerk SignUp component.
Error Message:
> Build error occurred
Error: Page "/sign-up/[[...sign-up]]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config.
    at C:\Users\bahaa\Desktop\learn-sphere\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1281:59
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\bahaa\Desktop\learn-sphere\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 5)
    at async C:\Users\bahaa\Desktop\learn-sphere\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1159:17
Component Code:
H

Here is my current component for the /sign-up/[[...sign-up]] route using Clerk's SignUp component:
import { SignUp } from '@clerk/nextjs';

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ signUp: [] }];
}

export default function SignUpPage() {
  return <SignUp />;
}
n

Next.config.js:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  reactStrictMode: true,
  typescript: {
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'utfs.io',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/**',
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default nextConfig;

Problem:
I am trying to deploy the app with output: 'export' (static export) in next.config.js, but the dynamic route /sign-up/[[...sign-up]] for Clerk requires generateStaticParams() because it’s dynamic. However, this is an authentication page, and I don't want it pre-rendered statically.
Question:
How can I handle dynamic routes like /sign-up/[[...sign-up]] when using Clerk in a static export configuration with Next.js?
Is there a way to prevent Clerk's dynamic routes from causing issues with the build process in static export mode?
Any help would be appreciated.
